# Visual Studio Console Application Installer - Schedule Windows Task

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, wix, scheduled-tasks

Does anyone know how to create an installation project using Visual Studio 2010 that creates a Windows Scheduler task?  I'm building an installer for a Console Application that needs to run every X minutes, and it would be nice for the customer not to have to schedule it manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WIX has its own custom action for creating windows task and scheduling them.

```
<CustomAction Id="CreateScheduledTask" Return="check" Directory="Application" ExeCommand="&quot;[SystemFolder]SCHTASKS.EXE&quot; /CREATE /SC DAILY /TN &quot;My Task&quot; /ST 12:00:00 /TR &quot;[INSTALLLOCATION]Apps\File.exe&quot; /RU [%USERDOMAIN]\[LogonUser]" />
```

Above command will create a task with name 'My Task' which will execute everyday at 12 AM.

[SCHTASKS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) command is used to create and schedule a windows task.

Comment: Thanks.  This works and was the simpler of the two approaches given so far.

Answer (score 2):

in Wix (.wixproj) you can do it in a CustomAction, written in Jscript, that invokes [Schtasks.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true) .

I don't know about VS2010's support of WIX, I think it is built-in.

The custom action module (the .js file) should have a function to run a schtasks command, something like this:

```
function RunSchtasksCmd(command, deleteOutput) {
    deleteOutput = deleteOutput || false;
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var tmpdir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.TemporaryFolder);
    var tmpFileName = fso.BuildPath(tmpdir, fso.GetTempName());
    var windir = fso.GetSpecialFolder(SpecialFolders.WindowsFolder);
    var schtasks = fso.BuildPath(windir,"system32\\schtasks.exe") + " " + command;

    // use cmd.exe to redirect the output
    var rc = shell.Run("%comspec% /c " + schtasks + "> " + tmpFileName, WindowStyle.Hidden, true);
    if (deleteOutput) {
        fso.DeleteFile(tmpFileName);
    }
    return {
        rc : rc,
        outputfile : (deleteOutput) ? null : tmpFileName
    };
}
```

And then, use that from within the custom action function itself, something like this

```
var r = RunSchtasksCmd("/Create Foo bar baz");
if (r.rc !== 0) {
    // 0x80004005 == E_FAIL
    throw new Error("exec schtasks.exe returned nonzero rc ("+r.rc+")");
}

var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var textStream = fso.OpenTextFile(r.outputfile, OpenMode.ForReading);

// Read from the file and parse the results.
while (!textStream.AtEndOfStream) {
    var oneLine = textStream.ReadLine();
    var line = ParseOneLine(oneLine); // look for errors?  success?
}
textStream.Close();
fso.DeleteFile(r.outputfile);
```

Some people say writing CA's in script is the wrong thing to do, because they are hard to maintain, hard to debug, or it's hard to do them right.  I think those are bad reasons. CA's implemented correctly in script, work well.

Comment: This is one way but WIX has inbuilt custom action which is better.

Comment: Ah, I did not know that. Much better to use the built-in thing.

Comment: I did try this and get it working, but it was a bit of work!  Thanks for the answer.  It looks like you spent some time on it, and I do apreciate that!

Comment: Eric, you're welcome. I didn't spend a whole lot of time on your question.  I had a similar question myself, and had solved it some time ago, so I just converted what I wrote for myself, to your situation.  It was 2 minutes. anyway I'm glad it was helpful.  I didn't know about the builtin custom action thing to run schtasks. it looks like that is simpler. In my case, I needed to parse the output of a command, and so simply executing a command as with the builtin capability, was not sufficient. You may not care about the output.